# Python selenium - set value using data-qa attribute

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following object,

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label data-qa="username-label"><span id="i18n-2">Username</span></label>
      <input id="ember4124" class="ember-view ember-text-field form-control" data-qa="username-input" type="text" value="">
    </div>
```

Here the input id "ember4124" changes every time. My requirement is find by data-qa "username-input" and pass the value, where value is the username.

Using below I can find the element,

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[data-qa='username-input']")

Output: [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="90144b65-8a86-4d54-90ae-4ccccab0cc9e", element="18e84265-46a7-41d8-a487-299e95ef7ae8")>]
```

But not sure how to send the value. Can anyone assist me?

Comment: probably there is only one element so use `element` (without `s` at the end) instead of `elements` to get only first element - `x = driver.find_element_...` `x.send_keys(...)`

Comment: Thanks furas. It worked as expected. Please post same as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is only one element so use `element` (without `s` at the end) instead of `elements` to get only first element and you will have

```
x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[data-qa='username-input']")
x.send_keys("James Bond")
```

---

If you will use `elements` (with `s` at the end) then you get list and you will have to use `[0]` to get first element on list

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[data-qa='username-input']")
x[0].send_keys("James Bond")
```